# what is src for script tags when they are in php include files

Tags: javascript, php

If I have a php include file which includes a `<script src = >` tag, where is the src relative to?
Is it relative to the original file or the include file?

If anyone could point me to a really good reference as I am moving a site around and all the paths are out and there are php include paths, css paths, image paths and javascript paths and they all have a different set of rules and now i have brain overload so asking for help :(

Thanks

Comment: This would take two minutes to test.

Comment: To get it clear in your head, it may be helpful to think about which component actually loads the resource. For example, scripts referenced by a `<script>` element are loaded by the web browser. They're therefore URLs that are relative to the web page that the browser is parsing. The browser will have no knowledge of the PHP include chain that pulls in the code that outputs the `<script>` element. It's just parsing the resulting web page.

Comment: Just put anything at all in it, then open the console and load the page. Look at the 404 paths. Or use `getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Since the `src` attribute is evaluated by the browser when it reads the HTML, it would be relative to the path in the browser. For example if the page is at `http://example.com/posts/show.php`, then `src="script.js"` would go to `http://example.com/posts/script.js`.

It is also possible to make it independent of the URL by using an absolute path: `src="/script.js"` would point to `http://example.com/script.js`.

Answer (score 0):

If you include a file in PHP it is the equivalent of copy and pasting the included file into the original file before it is processed. So the path is relative to the file that **does** the including.

folder/file.php:

```
<?php

echo("<img src='flower.png'>");

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php

include("folder/file.php");

?>
```

In this example, `flower.png` will only be shown if it is in the same directory as `index.php`

Try and use absolute urls wherever possible though, like:

`http://localhost/this/stuff.php`

`http://yoursite.com/this/stuff.php`

instead of `this/stuff.php`

Answer (score 0):

Include function generally do as it says. It include the data into your file, which means that the included data will act like it come from the file you include into. So it's relative to the original file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php